# banach space bigger than $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

we know that $L^p$ is banach space for any $p\geq 1$.

My question: Is there any other banach space that is bigger than $L^p$?.

In fact, I have an exercice that I don't have any idea: prove that space $(E,||.||_E)$ is banach space with norm
$$||f||_E = \sup_{p\geq 2} \frac{||f||_p}{\ln{p}}.$$

Could any one give me any idea for this?

Comment: What is $E$?. On the other hand, $\bigoplus_{p=1}^\infty L^p$ is $bigger$ than $L^p$

Comment: What should "bigger" be understood to mean in this context?

Comment: don't mind about "bigger". I just think how to deduce that $(E,||.||_E)$ is banach space from the fact that $L^p$ are banach spaces. Obviously, by the norm defini like above, E is normed vector space. Is it banach?

Comment: @anonymous Your inequality depends on the underlying measure space, which was not specified here. In particular, the two important properties for containment of $L^p$ spaces are whether the space contains sets of arbitrarily small positive measure, and whether the whole space is finite. In the former case, there are $L^p$ functions which are not $L^q$ for some $q>p$; in the latter case, there are $L^p$ functions which are not $L^q$ for some $q<p$.

Comment: Also, I don't think it is so obvious that your norm is a norm. The supremum could be attained at a different value of $p$ for $f,g$ and $f+g$ which makes the triangle inequality nontrivial. (The other properties are obvious.)

Comment: the triangle inequality is deduced from the triangle inequality on norm of $L^p$ and the fact that $\sup(A+B)\leq \sup(A)+\sup(B)$

Comment: none have idea for this question?